# Simple http helper in Go

Tags: go, http

Can you please share your thoughts on the following simple httphelper in Go? Thanks in advance.
I mainly would like to know whether returning a channel of a custom type seems like a good idea and if so , how could I improve it for only receive chans.

```
package services

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type HHResult struct {
    Result     string
    StatusCode int
    Error      error
}

type IHttpHelper interface {
    Request(method string, url string, headers map[string][]string, payload interface{}) chan HHResult
    RequestWithOptions(method string, url string, headers map[string][]string, payload interface{}) chan HHResult
}

var singleton IHttpHelper

type HttpHelper struct{}

func (h *HttpHelper) Request(method string, url string, headers map[string][]string, payload interface{}) chan HHResult {
    var result chan HHResult = make(chan HHResult)
    go func(output chan HHResult) {
        payl, err := json.Marshal(payload)
        if err != nil {
            result <- HHResult{
                Result:     "",
                StatusCode: 0,
                Error:      err,
            }
        }
        req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, bytes.NewReader(payl))
        client := http.Client{
            Timeout: time.Second * 30,
        }
        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            result <- HHResult{
                Result:     "",
                StatusCode: 0,
                Error:      err,
            }
        }
        respbytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        result <- HHResult{
            Result:     string(respbytes),
            StatusCode: resp.StatusCode,
            Error:      nil,
        }

    }(result)
    return result
}

func (h *HttpHelper) RequestWithOptions(method string, url string, headers map[string][]string, payload interface{}, timeout int) chan HHResult {
    var result chan HHResult = make(chan HHResult)
    go func(output chan<- HHResult) {
        payl, err := json.Marshal(payload)
        if err != nil {
            result <- HHResult{
                Result:     "",
                StatusCode: 0,
                Error:      err,
            }
        }
        req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, bytes.NewReader(payl))
        client := http.Client{
            Timeout: time.Second * timeout,
        }
        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            result <- HHResult{
                Result:     "",
                StatusCode: 0,
                Error:      err,
            }
        }
        respbytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        result <- HHResult{
            Result:     string(respbytes),
            StatusCode: resp.StatusCode,
            Error:      nil,
        }

    }(result)
    return result
}

func NewHttpHelper() IHttpHelper {
    if singleton == nil {
        singleton = &HttpHelper{}
    }
    return singleton
}
```

### Example of usage

```
func main() {
  helper := services.NewHttpHelper()
  res := <-helper.Request("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1", nil, nil)

 
  if res.Error != nil {
      fmt.Println(res.Error.Error())
      return
  }
  fmt.Println(res.StatusCode)
  fmt.Println(res.Result)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code is trying to do? `IHttpHelper` and `RequestWithOptions` aren't particularly descriptive names

Comment: they are just a wrapper on top of http operations. I want to GET, POST , etc from and endpoint and get a channel back with the response

Comment: Can you add a small example of a function that would use this then?

Comment: I have added a usage sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing in order the things I made note of/changed looking through your code:

1. `output chan HHResult` is declared but never used in `go funcs(output chan HHResult)`. It's fine that it's not used, the go func has access to  `Result` in the parent function, but you don't need to declare it if it's not needed.
2. The `headers` map argument is never used either.
3. Looking at `Request` and `RequestWithOptions` they're the same function except for the variable timeout. `Request` can be a small wrapper that just sets a default timeout then calls the more general function
4. Similarly, you repeatedly return the same `HHResult` only substituting which `err` is used so that can be pulled into it's own function `sendErr(chan, err)`
5. Any exported function or type (any that start with capital letters) should be commented
6. If you look in the `net/http` package you'll see it's standard to capitalize `HTTP` in variable names. Same with `JSON`.
7. Bugs:

a. One bug in your code is you send JSON via `http.Request` but you don't actually set the `Content-Type` to `application/json` which can cause issues with how your request is interpreted on the other end

b. Another bug is that the error in `respbytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)` is never used and you actually return `nil` for it whether or not you could actually read the body.

c. `Timeout: time.Second * 30` throws an error

8. As written, I don't see the need for the `IHTTPHelper` interface. `HttpHelper` has the only two methods used hanging directly from the struct and there's no way to inject a different type implementing the same interface into any of your code. As is `HttpHelper` alone does everything you need.
9. Purely stylistically, I think some of the variable names like `HHResults` are confusing and rewrote them

---

```
package services

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

// HelperResponse is the response returned by an HTTPHelper.Request()
type HelperResponse struct {
    Result     string
    StatusCode int
    Error      error
}

// HTTPHelper hangs Request and RequestWithTimeout methods
type HTTPHelper struct{}

var singleton *HTTPHelper

// NewHTTPHelper returns a pointer to the HTTPHelper singleton
func NewHTTPHelper() *HTTPHelper {
    if singleton == nil {
        singleton = &HTTPHelper{}
    }
    return singleton
}

func sendErr(out chan HelperResponse, err error) {
    out <- HelperResponse{
        Result:     "",
        StatusCode: 0,
        Error:      err,
    }
}

// Request wraps RequestWithTimeout with default 30 second timeout
func (h *HTTPHelper) Request(method string, url string, payload interface{}) (out chan HelperResponse) {
    return h.RequestWithTimeout(method, url, payload, 30)
}

// RequestWithTimeout returns Response, StatusCode, and any Errors from an http request
func (h *HTTPHelper) RequestWithTimeout(method string, url string, payload interface{}, timeout int) (out chan HelperResponse) {
    go func() {
        payloadJSON, err := json.Marshal(payload)
        if err != nil {
            sendErr(out, err)
        }

        req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, bytes.NewReader(payloadJSON))
        req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

        client := http.Client{Timeout: time.Second * time.Duration(timeout)}

        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            sendErr(out, err)
        }

        respBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        defer resp.Body.Close()

        out <- HelperResponse{
            Result:     string(respBytes),
            StatusCode: resp.StatusCode,
            Error:      err,
        }
    }()

    return out
}
```

Comment: Your comments are awesome. Ill rewrite this!

Comment: One more note, you'll see in my rewrite I used named returns (`out` specifically) in the function definition. If you haven't seen that before it saves one line but is pretty much a stylistic choice, not required